# How to display newline / CR in toast()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to include newlines in a `toast()` message, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Actions effectués: " + chargement + "\n Durée moyenne:\n - 10 + 32 par groupes simples \n - 42 + (64/groupes) pour les groupes composés.", "Chargement en cours:\n", 2);
```

Is there a way to do that, or an alternative? (Because I doubt this is possible, that's not like if my code was hard to understand so I could have done a mistake.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `msgBox()` and `inputBox()`, you can post multi-line messages by escaping the slash on `\n`:

```js
Browser.msgBox("line 1\\nline 2\\nline 3");
```

The same trick does not work for `toast()`, unfortunately.

Another old trick is to pad out the lines of your messages with spaces or non-breaking spaces, to force following text onto the next line. This is effective, but bothersome.

So here's a utility to do that without the bother! (Part of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0).) Wouldn't you like to do this?

```js
function testToaster() {
  var myToast = new Toaster( "Actions effectués: " + chargement + "\n Durée moyenne:\n - 10 + 32 par groupes simples \n - 42 + (64/groupes) pour les groupes composés.", "Chargement en cours:\n", 2);
  myToast.display();
}
```

If you knew the exact width of every character plus any internal padding, and the exact width of the display area, you could pad out each string perfectly. This utility isn't that exact, but it's pretty close.

```js
/**
 * "Class" Toaster
 *
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/a/33552904/1677912
 *
 * Wrapper for Spreadsheet.toast() with support for multi-line messages.
 *
 * Constructor:    new Toaster( message, title, timeoutSeconds );
 *
 * @param message         {String}    Toast message, possibly with newlines (`\n`)
 * @param title           {String}    (optional) Toast title
 * @param timeoutSeconds  {Number}    (optional) Duration of display, default 3s
 *
 * @returns {Toaster}                 Toaster instance.
 */
var Toaster = function(message, title, timeoutSeconds) {
  if (typeof message == 'undefined')
    throw new TypeError( "missing message" );

  this.message = this.parseMessage(message);
  this.title = title || '';
  this.timeoutSeconds = timeoutSeconds || 3;
  this.ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
};

/**
 * Display Toaster message using previously set parameters.
 */
Toaster.prototype.display = function() {
  this.ss.toast(this.message,this.title,this.timeoutSeconds);
}

/**
 * This is where the magic happens. Prepares multi-line messages for display.
 *
 * @param {String} msg    Toast message, possibly with newlines (`\n`)
 *
 * @returns{String}       Message, ready to display.
 */
Toaster.prototype.parseMessage = function( msg ) {
  var maxWidth = 52;             // Approx. number of non-breaking spaces required to span toast popup.
  var knob = 1.85;               // Magical approx. ratio of avg char width : non-breaking space width
  var parsedMessage = '';

  var lines = msg.split('\n');   // Break lines at newline chars

  // Rebuild message with padded lines
  for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    var len = lines[i].length;
    // Build padding string of non-breaking spaces sandwiched with normal spaces.
    var padding = ' '
                + len < (maxWidth / knob) ?
                  Array(Math.floor(maxWidth-(lines[i].length * knob))).join(String.fromCharCode(160)) + ' ' : '';
    parsedMessage += lines[i] + padding;
  }
  return parsedMessage;
}
```

Comment: Waiting for having time to see it. But looks like it will resolve my issue. Thx mate.

Comment: You are the best bro.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same, but I found \r seemed to work. Try:
`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Actions effectués: " + chargement + "\r Durée moyenne:\r - 10 + 32 par groupes simples \r - 42 + (64/groupes) pour les groupes composés.", "Chargement en cours:\r", 2);`